# Does every expression in C have a value? How about the function call with void as a result?

Tags: c

As titled.

```
void foo() {}
int main(void) {
  foo();  // what is the value of this expression?
}
```

Does it mean that `void` is also a type of value in C? Or how should I understand that?

Comment: Add to the confusion... `void` isn't a really a type, but `void *` is...

Comment: `// what is the value of this expression?` - nothing, it will just execute the `foo()` function.

Answer (score 1):

A **void expression** has no value, and in fact cannot be used.  This is described in detail in section 6.3.2.2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The (nonexistent) value of a *void expression* (an expression that has
> type `void`) shall not be  used  in  any way, and  implicit  or
> explicit  conversions  (except  to `void`) shall  not  be applied  to
> such  an  expression. If an  expression  of  any other  type  is
> evaluated  as  a  void
> expression,  its  value  or  designator  is  discarded. (A  void
> expression  is  evaluated  for  its
> side effects.)